# It's a nice vista!

Tags: word-choice

I overheard someone use the term "**vista**" while describing a view. Being a non-native speaker, I would have chosen the simpler form: "**It's a nice view.**" Could some generous soul explain when it's a *vista* and when it's a *view*? Are these interchangeable in most circumstances?

Comment: Windows Vista is a clue

Comment: @shinynewbike: Is it?

Comment: @Urbycoz: Yes, it's just a fancy name ;)

Comment: @shinynewbike: lol, you got that right! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vista is Italian for view. (Also Spanish, but adopted from Italian: see [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=vista).)

It has been adopted into the English language and retains the same (noun) meaning, except that it is generally only applied to picturesque views.

For example:

> Hey, lets pull over and take in the vista.

or

> You should come out onto the balcony, there is a beautiful vista of the city below.

According to Google NGram, usage in this fashion didn't really take off until after 1900

[image: Google NGram for "take in the vista,enjoy the vista"]

however the phrase "beautiful vista" seems to have been around for a long while

[image: Google NGram for "beautiful vista"]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, they're interchangeable in most circumstances.

Long answer: 'View' is a more generic word.  'Vista' is specifically referring to a physical view (especially one through a long, narrow passage of eg. trees), or a similarly metaphorical long view: a long-term view of the future, for example.

Either that or a dodgy operating system.

Comment: I'd say 'vista' was an expansive rather than restricted view, but it's certainly not *different* from 'view'.